# Why does Ansible win_package not uninstall Notepad++?

Tags: ansible, notepad++

Ansible v2.11.0

Instead of `win_chocolatey`, I ended up installing `Notepad++` via `win_package` module.

```
- name: "Install {{ notepadpp_product_id }} version {{ notepadpp_version }}"
  win_package:
    path: "{{ remote_temp }}\\notepadplusplus.exe"
    arguments: /S
    product_id: "{{ notepadpp_product_id }}"
    state: present
  when: install
```

and I get this when I run the playbook, and Notepad++ is indeed installed and I see it in `C:\Program Files\Notepad++``

```
TASK [exa-prereqs : Install Notepad++ (64-bit x64) version 7.9.5] **************
changed: [10.227.xx.xx]
```

However when I run the uninstaller, by passing a `-e '{install: false}'`, it doesn't get uninstalled, that is, `C:\Program Files\Notepad++` folder and contents are still there, and still shows up in `Control Panel -> Uninstall programs` list.

```
- name: "Uninstall {{ notepadpp_product_id }} version {{ notepadpp_version }}"
  win_package:
    path: "{{ notepadpp_install_dir }}\\uninstall.exe"
    arguments: /S
    product_id: "{{ notepadpp_product_id }}"
    state: absent
  ignore_errors: true
  when: not install
```

I see this when running the playbook with verbose option.

```
TASK [exa-prereqs : Uninstall Notepad++ (64-bit x64) version 7.9.5] ************
task path: /path/ansible/exa-playbooks/roles/exa-prereqs/tasks/notepadpp.yml:16
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.win_package to ansible.windows.win_package
Using module file /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/3.3.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/modules/win_package.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<10.227.xx.xx> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: jenkins on PORT 5986 TO 10.227.xx.xx
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
ok: [10.227.xx.xx] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "arguments": "/S",
            "chdir": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_cert_password": null,
            "creates_path": null,
            "creates_service": null,
            "creates_version": null,
            "expected_return_code": [
                0,
                3010
            ],
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "headers": null,
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "log_path": null,
            "maximum_redirection": 50,
            "password": null,
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\uninstall.exe",
            "product_id": "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)",
            "provider": "auto",
            "proxy_password": null,
            "proxy_url": null,
            "proxy_use_default_credential": false,
            "proxy_username": null,
            "state": "absent",
            "url_method": null,
            "url_password": null,
            "url_timeout": 30,
            "url_username": null,
            "use_default_credential": false,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "username": null,
            "validate_certs": true,
            "wait_for_children": false
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "reboot_required": false
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

Odd thing is, I use the same task for uninstalling another package (7-Zip) and it works for that. What gives?

Comment: Did you see the [relevant looking bug](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3220#issuecomment-298793154)?

Comment: Separately, having `ignore_errors: true` on tasks is a recipe for generating SO questions; why is it there?

Comment: @mdaniel, if un-installation runs successfully, it will remove the `uninstall.exe` file, and so subsequently re-running the playbook will fail w/o the `ignore_errors: true`

Comment: @mdaniel, adding the `/ALLUSERS=TRUE` option per bug report didn't help.

Comment: IMHO that's a pretty heavy-handed way to avoid a `stat:` call that would preserve the idempotency of your playbook without eating _every_ error; anyway, back to your question at hand, what is the behavior if you remove the `/S` (which I presume stands for `/SILENT`)? Is that jenkins user a member of the Administrator group? Have you tried flipping `wait_for_children: true` in case the uninstaller is forking off a child process?

Comment: @mdaniel, I'll look into the `stat:` call since I like the idea of preserving idempotency. Yes jenkins user is an admin, and yes `/S` stands for silent, and removing it just pends on an action (task waits, until it times out). I'll try `wait_for_children: true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with the same problem recently so I post my findings here.

If you list the packages with choco:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> choco list --localonly
Chocolatey v1.2.1
chocolatey 1.2.1
chocolatey-compatibility.extension 1.0.0
chocolatey-core.extension 1.4.0
notepadplusplus 8.4.9
notepadplusplus.install 8.4.9
```

...you will see two entries for Nodepad++.

In my ansible playbook I created two task: one for notepadplusplus and one for notepadplusplus.install

```
- name: "Gather stats for {{ notepadpp_install_location }}"
    win_stat:
      path: "{{ notepadpp_install_location }}"
    register: notepadpp_dir
      
- name: "Uninstall {{ notepadpp_product_id }} version {{ notepadpp_version }}"
    win_package:
      path: "{{ notepadpp_install_location }}\\uninstall.exe"
      arguments: /S
      product_id: "{{ notepadpp_product_id }}"
      state: absent
    when: notepadpp_dir.stat.exists == True

  - name: "Uninstall {{ notepadpp_product_id}}.install version {{ notepadpp_version }}"
    win_chocolatey:
      name: "{{ notepadpp_product_id}}.install"
      version: "{{ notepadpp_version }}"
      state: absent
```

variables

```
notepadpp_product_id: notepad++
notepadpp_product_name: notepadplusplus
notepadpp_version: 8.4.9
notepadpp_install_location: C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++
```

*thanks to my co-worker Marco for pointing out notepadplusplus.install*

Comment: Very cool to know the `choco list ...` command, thanks!